# Automatically create a new Google Sheets when creating a Google Slides from templates gallery

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm using a Google Slides document (saved in the templates gallery) to make client reports.
This Slides is linked with a Google Sheets for data graphs.

My problem :
When I create a new Slide from the gallery, it doesn't create a new Sheets to go with, but it take datas from the same Sheets I created the template with. If I modify datas, all my other Slides client reports are then false...

Is there a way through Google Apps Script to automatically create a copy of the Sheets file when I create a new Slides from this template, and link all datas ?

Comment: Does the template file have a script? How are the slide and sheet linked?

Comment: No the template doesn't have any script. It's a very simple file.

Comment: The link is made by copying a graph from Sheets in Slides. This way, you can update the graph when changes are made into the Sheets datas.

Comment: Can you explain how you create the graph and how it's copied over?

Comment: The chart is created in Sheets just like any other chart. It's a pretty simple line chart. To copy the chart from Sheets to Slides, just Cmd-C / Cmd-V.